# Correct way to test http request URL's in Angular 2

Tags: jasmine, angular, angular2-services

Using Angular 2 I have set up a few services and each method inside returns a different http request, something like this:

```
public create(user:User): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.post(this._apiUrls.create,
    JSON.stringify(user), {
      headers: this.apiConfig.getApiHeaders()
    });
}
```

I want to test this method. I'm testing the request url, the headers, and the user. I'm a bit stuck on the url part, I can test the actual url but I can't figure out how to test if it's a GET, POST etc... In Angular 1 we used something like expectGET or expectPOST. This is how I'm doing it so far:

```
beforeEachProviders(() => [
  MockBackend,
  BaseRequestOptions,
  provide(Http, {
    useFactory: (backend, defaultOptions) => new Http(backend, defaultOptions),
    deps: [MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions]
  }),
  ApiConfig,
  Authentication
]);

it('Should make a request to login a new user', inject([Authentication, MockBackend], (service, mockBackend) => {
  let connection;
  connection = mockBackend.connections.subscribe(c => connection = c);
  service.create(setUser()).subscribe((res) => {
    expect(connection.request.url).toBe(service.apiConfig.getApiRoot()+'api/identities/login');
    expect(connection.request._body).toEqual(JSON.stringify(setUser()));
  });
  connection.mockRespond(200);
}));
```

Any idea how to get the type of request it is? Or am I just doing it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently (beta.3) no easy way to test this (like `expectGET` in AngularJS 1.x), but you are on the right track.

You can do:

```
service.create(setUser()).subscribe((res) => {
  expect(res.request.method).toBe(RequestMethod.Post);
});
```

I opened an issue a while ago to have a nicer API for test, you can [follow it on Github](https://github.com/angular/http/issues/58)

Comment: this seems not to be valid for rc1

Answer (score -1):

Instead of calling `http.get` or `http.post`, you can call `http.request` with a `Request` object. The class API is [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/Request-class.html). The first member is a value of the [RequestMethod](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/RequestMethod-enum.html) enumerated type, so you should be able to test that in Jasmine.